# How to use Array.Splice properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to use Array.Splice properly?

```
var myEmptyData = [];
myEmptyData = $.parseJSON('[{
    "m_sPartNumber": "B104-92",
    "m_sJobStep": "0300",
    "m_sQTY": "170.000",
    "m_sRunHrs": "0.1400",
    "m_sRunPriority": "20150403      MAFC8X0114229",
    "m_sMO": "MU43380",
    "m_sAssemblyMO": "MAFC8X0",
    "m_sDesc": "B104-92 TP DWR FRT",
    "m_sTagID": "",
    "m_sWorkCenter": "AL018",
    "isWandOn": "N"
}, {
    "m_sPartNumber": "B228-53",
    "m_sJobStep": "0300",
    "m_sQTY": "21.000",
    "m_sRunHrs": "0.0441",
    "m_sRunPriority": "20150403      MAFDCL0190143",
    "m_sMO": "M085780",
    "m_sAssemblyMO": "MAFDCL0",
    "m_sDesc": "B228-53  VAL",
    "m_sTagID": "",
    "m_sWorkCenter": "AL028",
    "isWandOn": "N"
}, {
    "m_sPartNumber": "B175-93",
    "m_sJobStep": "0300",
    "m_sQTY": "228.000",
    "m_sRunHrs": "0.7296",
    "m_sRunPriority": "20150406      MAFDC60132094",
    "m_sMO": "M947070",
    "m_sAssemblyMO": "MAFDC60",
    "m_sDesc": "B175-93 LF SD",
    "m_sTagID": "",
    "m_sWorkCenter": "AL004",
    "isWandOn": "N"
}, {
    "m_sPartNumber": "B131-85",
    "m_sJobStep": "0300",
    "m_sQTY": "150.000",
    "m_sRunHrs": "0.4500",
    "m_sRunPriority": "20150406      MAFDDJ0162969",
    "m_sMO": "M964230",
    "m_sAssemblyMO": "MAFDDJ0",
    "m_sDesc": "B131-85  LF MTR LEG",
    "m_sTagID": "",
    "m_sWorkCenter": "AL014",
    "isWandOn": "N"
}, {
    "m_sPartNumber": "B175-93",
    "m_sJobStep": "0300",
    "m_sQTY": "228.000",
    "m_sRunHrs": "0.7296",
    "m_sRunPriority": "20150406      MAFDC60132097",
    "m_sMO": "M947130",
    "m_sAssemblyMO": "MAFDC60",
    "m_sDesc": "B175-93 RT SD",
    "m_sTagID": "",
    "m_sWorkCenter": "AL004",
    "isWandOn": "N"
}]');

var myEmptyDataNew = myEmptyData.splice(4, 1);
```

Comment: Why it's not working? What's the result you were expecting and the result you got? Be specific and write your questions carefully so someone can understand it and help you.

Comment: when i perform this var myEmptyDataNew = myEmptyData.splice(4, 1);
I expect  myEmptyDataNew to have three records but the myEmptyData.splice(4, 1); always returns only one element no matter what index i pass to splice function

Comment: Google "mdn splice" > https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/splice

Answer (score 1):

`splice` works correctly(inline on array).

`splice` returns the removed item.

```
myEmptyData.splice(4, 1);
console.log(myEmptyData);
```

> The splice() method changes the content of an array by removing existing elements and/or adding new elements.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/1ztL1jbd/

Comment: My bad! :D You are correct! I didnt read the definition of splice properly!